# Ubuntu Stopped working due to removed packages that have been gone for months

Tags: unity, desktop-environments, awn

I've customized my install by stripping out all the unity packages that make the system unusable for me and replaced panels with AWN.

```
sudo apt-get remove unity unity-asset-pool unity-lens-applications unity-lens-files unity-lens-music unity-lens-video unity-scope-musicstores unity-scope-video-remote
```

Then removed all the programs i didnt want

```
sudo apt-get auto-remove libreoffice* gwibber empathy shotwell firefox thunderbird brasero
```

It has worked for months. now suddenly it cant load session Ubuntu.

So i switched ttys and installed `ubuntu-desktop` again and it reinstalled all of `unity libreoffice brasero firefox shotwell thunderbird gwibber empathy` and a handful of other stuff i cannot stand and didn't want.

And removing any of the offending packages now breaks Ubuntu again and needs to be reinstalled. So now I'm stuck with unity AND my awn panels and window decorations that are more useless than anything I've ever seen (cant move windows around menus are stuck to the top and uclickable). how do i fix this?

Comment: You have removed `unity`, but did you replace it with other desktop environment?

Comment: Yes Awn As Mentioned. Unity hasnt been fully removed. only the unity panel packages and nautilus add ins. here is how it looked and ran for the last 8 months

http://i.imgur.com/EQoC4BF.jpg

Comment: worth noting this is the guide used it replacing unity with AWN

http://lunaticdroid.blogspot.com/2012/06/guide-beautifying-ubuntu-part-1.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks as if the problem magically fixed itself, after using this for the last few days the errors went away with no changes made and my desktop is back to normal. i have no idea why.